# Next.js refresh values without reloading page in props list

Tags: reactjs, next.js

probably I got a little bit lost on the following task. I have an admin page in my application where you can see all the posts from the plattform. I'm requesting the posts from an api and Im displaying them on the page as a list. I Inserted two buttons to enable/disable the post by calling a function which does tag the post to be enabled/disabled.

Everything works fine, but I want to change the state of the button without reloading the page. Im passing `disable` parameter threw the button tag. I don't know why its not working, if I `console.log` the values its already changed there. Is this a proper way to use `useeffect`? I tried to use it but I failed using it correct.

Somebody can help please?

Simplified Code ( I removed the enable function, since its nearly the same like disable)

```
export default function Feed(props) {

  const [postStatus, setPostStatus] = useState(props.posts)


  async function disablePost(id, e){
    e.preventDefault();

    const userInput = { postId: id }

    try{
      const res = await axios.post(`${baseurl}/api/auth/admin/disable-post`, userInput, {
    })


    var currentPostStatus = postStatus;
    currentPostStatus.map((el) => {
      if(el.id === id){
        el.disabled = true;
      }
      console.log(el.id)
    });


     setPostStatus(currentPostStatus)
    console.log(postStatus)

    }catch(error){
      console.log(error)
      return
    }
  }


  return (
    <>
    <HeaderAdmin></HeaderAdmin>
    <div>
      {/* {console.log(props.userCount)} */}
      <p>Alle Posts</p>

      {postStatus.map((post) => 
      
            <React.Fragment key={post.id}>
              <p>{post.id}</p>
              <p>{post.email}</p>
              <p>{post.desc}</p>
              <p>{post.disabled == true ? 'Post deaktviert' : 'Post aktiviert'}</p>
      
              <button disabled={ post.disabled } onClick={(e) => disablePost(post.id, e)}>Post deaktivieren</button>
              <button disabled={ !post.disabled } onClick={(e) => enablePost(post.id, e)}>Post aktivieren</button>
            </React.Fragment>
        )}
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screen can't refresh to the new version after you clicked the `disable` or `enable`.

```
    var currentPostStatus = postStatus;
    currentPostStatus.map((el) => {
      if(el.id === id){
        el.disabled = true;
      }
    });
```

In your code, you are only changing the internal property of `postStatus`, but *React* only cares about the reference of the object. so you need  to do

```
    setPostStatus([...currentPostStatus])
```

The above line create a new array. I personally believe this is something *React* should improve in the future, because half of the question about *React* in stackoverflow is talking about this :)

Comment: Note that `map` is being used here, meaning that `currentPostStatus` will not be mutated. You need to retrieve the array returned by the `map` and pass that to the set state function.